# JSON array to table exclude columns

Tags: php, jquery, json

I wrote a simple function that takes one of my database tables and outputs a full JSON array.

```
function tableJSON ($table, $orderby) {
    $array = array();
    $sql = Nemesis::select("*", $table, NULL, $orderby);
    if ($sql) {
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                // push row values to array
                array_push($array, $row);
            }
            return json_encode($array);
        } else {
            echo 'Query returned empty';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Query error';
    }
}
```

From this array a table is generated using a method outlined [here](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table/). Then I apply table sorter to the table. My question is that, currently, this script outputs all rows and columns. Example:

```
[{"id":"109225488","project_name":"One on One Interview the Dean of RSM","project_bold":"Interview","project_content":"Interview with the Dean of Erasmus University Rotterdam School of Management. Interviewer: Joost Kammermans.","project_image_1":"\/images\/uploads\/projects\/109225488\/m_109225488_1.jpg","project_image_2":"","project_image_3":"","project_image_4":"","youtube_link":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=9rsR3FcLAxI","published":"1","created":"2013-05-29 14:07:49","created_by":"1","last_modified":"2013-07-22 19:43:15","last_modified_by":"1"}
```

How would I exclude this script from outputting an array of excluded columns?

For example:

`$excluded = array('created_by', 'project_image_1');`

I have tried `array_diff`, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = Nemesis::select("*", $table, NULL, $orderby);
```

Change the `*` to a list of only the columns you want output and you won't have to worry about fussing with the array on the backend.

Comment: interesting point, but in my own interest i am curious. ill upvote in any case

Comment: I agree - dealing with only the columns you need is your best bet - you don't have to sift through the data in a strange way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest DevIshOne's answer, but...

```
function tableJSON ($table, $orderby, $excluded = array()) {
    $array = array();
    $sql = Nemesis::select("*", $table, NULL, $orderby);
    if ($sql) {
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $newrow = array();

                foreach($row as $col => $val)
                    if(!in_array($col, $excluded))
                        $newrow[$col] = $val;
                // push row values to array
                array_push($array, $newrow);
            }
            return json_encode($array);
        } else {
            echo 'Query returned empty';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Query error';
    }
}
```